# What is difference b/w sealed and abstract classes in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to know in what   scenario we can use sealed classes and abstract class.please explain with example.

Comment: Sealed classes are abtract, with the addition of them having a known, enumerable set of subtypes. See: https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#sealed

Answer (score 0):

class marked by abstract Modifier has the following rules:

- **can't be instantiated.**
- **can contain abstract methods**(methods without implementation),       generally abstract methods can be found only within abstract classes or interfaces.
- **can be extended and implemented by client classes**(in this cases       client classes are responsible for the implementation of abstract       method within the super class).

the above rules are the same for sealed classes, **if and only if** the client classes are declared within the library(file) in which the sealed super class is declared!!

**sealed class can be extended and implemented also, but when the client class is declared within the same dart file of the sealed superclass** it's a privacy related.
as you know privacy in dart is library level rather than class level.

ok, **in fact sealed modifier is the same as abstract modifier except for exhaustiveness,**

so, what is the exhaustiveness which the sealed class provides,

exhaustive in short: all possible types or cases must be covered

example

```
// Non-exhaustive switch on bool?, missing case to match null possibility:
switch (nullableBool) {
  case true:
    print('yes');
  case false:
    print('no');
}
```

the above switch statement doesn't cover all the possible cases of the nullableBoll(true,false,null) so, it's not an exhaustive switch.

Q: is it mandatory for a switch to be exhaustive?
the answer depends on the switch expression (what you are switching over) is **enumerated type or object that has a sealed superclass.**

example:

```
sealed class Shape {}

class Square implements Shape {}

class Circle implements Shape {}

void main() {
 Shape p = Circle();
  switch (p) {
    case Circle():
      print('circle');
      break;
    
  }
}
```

the above code is generating an error and the **IDE is alerting me** *The type 'Shape' is not exhaustively matched by the switch cases since it doesn't match 'Square()'.
Try adding a default case or cases that match 'Square()'.*

it needs me to add the square case or default case, it needs the switch to be exhaustive. the same occurs with enumerated types.

**if the super class Shape is an abstract so, it's not mandatory to cover all of the possible values (can be inexhaustive switch).**

coming to the 1m question? where and when to use each modifier?

abstract :

> you don't care about the location of the client class (it can be
> inside the superclass library or not). preferable when you offer
> openness. you don't require  to make Exhaustiveness checking.

sealed:

> the location of the client classes must be in the same library of the
> super classes (super and sub classes in the same dart file).
>
> you care about Exhaustiveness checking.

at last, i should inform the reader of that answer this answer is open for enhancement and refactoring and modification and may it didn't cover all of the possible info (exhaustive ^-^).

hope it helps you.